# How can I apply consistent indentation and formatting to Nginx config files?

Tags: nginx, config, formatter

I have got this messy config for example:

```
server {
listen 80 default;
                        server_name localhost;
location / {
proxy_method $foo;
                    proxy_pass http://foobar:8080;
}
}
```

and I would like to make it look like:

```
server
{
    listen 80 default;
    server_name localhost;
    location /
    {
        proxy_method $foo;
        proxy_pass http://foobar:8080;
    }
}
```

How can I format Nginx configurations in a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few formatters out there, such as:

1. [Nginx Formatter](https://github.com/1connect/nginx-config-formatter) ([python](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/blurb/)) by 1connect which has a nice locally runable tool, works very good!
2. [Nginx Formatter](http://blindage.org/?p=8061) ([python](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/blurb/))at blindage.org , didnt try that one but it seems good by his example outputs.
3. [Nginx Beautifier](https://nginxbeautifier.com)([javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp)) also available at [nginxbeautifier.com](https://nginxbeautifier.com) as a tiny js tool just like [jsbeautifier.com](https://jsbeautifier.com) and of course also open source on [github](https://github.com/vasilevich/nginxbeautifier) you can run it locally too by:

[installing it from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nginxbeautifier)([nodejs package manager](https://www.npmjs.com/)):

```
npm install -G nginxbeautifier
```

[installing it from arch aur](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/nginxbeautifier/) ([arch user repository](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository)):

```
pacaur -S nginxbeautifier
```

[cloning from by github repository](https://github.com/vasilevich/nginxbeautifier)([git](https://git-scm.com/) and [github](https://github.com)):

```
git clone https://github.com/vasilevich/nginxbeautifier.git
```

instructions on how to use the program locally are available once you
execute
nginxbeautifier -h
or
nginxbeautifier --help
and also on the github page itself.

Full disclosure I am the developer and the maintainer of "nginxbeautifier.com"
and the relevant github page
please report any issuses there,
some of the code in nginxbeautifier was 
acctualy inspired by the first option mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Any online / text editor's code beautifier should do the work, experiment with different languages to get the perfect indentations.

http://jsbeautifier.org/

Sample output from above website:

```
server {
    listen 80
    default;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_method $foo;
        proxy_pass http: //foobar:8080;
    }
}
```